# How to say "within" / "in the context of"/ "as a part of"?

Tags: usage, expressions

Many times I have interchanged the English phrase "in frames of" into Japanese "~の一環｛いっかん}として" or "~の一環で". Although not so long ago I have noticed, that it is not as natural expression in Japanese... could you please tell some better way, in which I should express this English phrase? I will also write some examples:

> 入社手続き{にゅうしゃてつづき}の一環として
>
> **within**/**in the context of**/ **as a part of** formalities related to entering the company
>
> 是正措置｛ぜせいそち}の一環として :
>
> **within**/**in the context of**/ **as a part of**  corrective measures
>
> 日系企業｛にっけいきぎょう}での実習｛じっしゅう}の一環として
>
> **within**/**in the context of**/ **as a part of**  practice in Japanese company

Sorry for any confusion and thank you for your kind support.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand, but I think you mean "in the frame of". i.e "considering all things related to ...". Right?

Comment: I have no idea what *in frames of* means, so this question is difficult for me to understand.

Comment: "in frame of" probably means "in boundary of".

Comment: That doesn't mean anything to me either, so the only way I can assign any meaning to these phrases is by reading the Japanese . . .

Comment: @snailplane **In the framework of** the standard model of particle physics proton decay is forbidden. **In the framework of** European politics countries cannot make their own trade agreements. I think that's the sort of thing she means.

Comment: Perhaps 仕組み would be a better translation for "framework", and "一環として should be interpreted as  "a part of".  The question seems ill formed.

Comment: Maybe "in the context of"?

Comment: Your chosen Japanese examples translate as follows: // As part of the entry procedure // As part of the corrective action // As part of the practical training of Japanese companies

Comment: I have never heard "in frames of". Surprisingly, it comes out A LOT in a Google search. Many English natives seems very surprised as well. Some have discovered that it seems to be a bad turn of phrase very used by Russians, Armenians, etc. Most natives would probably tell you that it makes no sense or that it is useless.(could be completely removed from the sentence without any impact on it.). Just out of curiosity, can I ask what is your native language and country? As far as Japanese go, I would suggest you use something like にとって、に対して、の場合, etc...

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments. 
No no, not a framework. The phrase used in English is "in frames of", it has quiet a wide usage, at least in Europe. If you say you don't know it, looks like it is not grammatically correct. The meaning is "within/beyond/under" - I will make some changes in the topic...
@ConMan, "in the context of" has very close meaning to a Japanese phrase, which I am trying to find out.

Comment: I'm with @snailplane here. Native speaker of AmE, living in Japan (where I encounter BrE from time to time). "In frames of" is definitely not a construction I would understand if used. I would assume it was a non-native user misspeaking for either "in terms of" or "in light of"

Comment: @virmaior , Thank you for your comment. Now I understand the reason of the confusion. This time I have learnt more then expected... but I am very glad... From now I will be using "in terms of" or "in light of"!

Answer (score 2):

The three *Japanese* phrases you posted are perfectly natural on their own. They mean "as part of ～". It's a bit stiff expression, but can be used in casual conversations, too. 一環として is preferred over 一部として when it refers to a project, procedure, event, etc., that may take a long time. [Lots of examples on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=as%20part%20of&ref=sa).

If you mean something different by "in frames of", please let me know.

Comment: Dear @naruto , thank you so much for your kind reply. Yes, I have meant exactly this. 
Excuse me, the phrase "in frames of" is used so much in my area, so I even haven't noticed, that it is not a usual English. I change it.
I see... thank you so much for understanding and for the explanation.